# How to calculate how many days probability of each stage avilable

Tags: apex, soql, community, reporting, opportunity

I want to how many days an `Opportunity` record resides in each stage. When prospecting to either `Closed Won` or `Closed Lost`. Is there better way to count the number of days for a single stage?

We need to report on all `Opportunity` records based on this criteria. But it is not ideal to create a field for each specific stage. We have a lot of stages set up.

I find a solution for this problem.But it is now closed.

For Reference:

[image: Probability report]

we have specific probability for specific stage.So,now we can easily differentiate how many days a opportunity resides in specific stage.

Comment: You want to know how long the opportunity was at each stage but you are looking for a solution where you do not have a field to time-stamp each individual stage change. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm thinking to write a process to get the time stamp whenever stage is changed @jatuttle0

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use apex & triggers.

1) Create custom object(Opty_stage_days) that have fields like opp_id, days_in_prospect_stage, days_in_Negotiate_stage, days_in_contract_stage, etc

2) Write after trigger to check if stage is changed 
if yes then call recalculate method on those opp ids

3) in recalculate method update/insert the record in Opty_stage_days. You will need to update the column with number of days in which oppty was there eg. fpry1 was in respecting stage for 10 days.

4) to get the exact count you can also use information generated by audit tracing. If your data set is really large consider more appropriate solution with flags, batch an scheduler

5) Once the data is available in Opty_stage_days then you can generate many reports on it.

for ex.
 1) avg of each stage

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [Report on Historical Data with Reporting Snapshots](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US).

> A reporting snapshot lets you report on historical data. Authorized users can save tabular or summary report results to fields on a custom object, then map those fields to corresponding fields on a target object. They can then schedule when to run the report to load the custom object's fields with the report's data. Reporting snapshots enable you to work with report data similarly to how you work with other records in Salesforce.

Report on the `Id` and `StageName` fields and pull it daily. You can then use this data to determine how long a record was in each stage.

Comment: But the problem is.If i want to try to reporting on quarterly or yearly basis. @Adrian Larson

Comment: That is a "problem" how exactly?

Comment: Hey thanks @Adrian Larson i am working on this to get a better solution

Comment: Hey i got a solution for this problem @Adrian Larson